# Modifying shapes in a group of shapes

Tags: vba, excel

The code is going through a series of shapes inside a group of shapes.
The `grp`variable is set as a *Public shape variable* earlier in the process of selecting the group of shapes that needs to be modified, like this: `ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ParentGroup`

Each shape needs a couple of different configurations done based upon which item in the group, and based on the supplied string `selVal`.

```
Sub changeGroup(selVal As String)

If selVal = "Fordon" Then
    grp.GroupItems(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
    grp.GroupItems(2).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
    grp.GroupItems(3).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
ElseIf selVal = "Fotg" Then
    grp.GroupItems(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
    grp.GroupItems(2).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
    grp.GroupItems(3).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
ElseIf selVal = "Kollektiv" Then
    grp.GroupItems(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "S"
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 11
    grp.GroupItems(2).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "-"
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 9
    grp.GroupItems(3).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "h"
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 11
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = "Wingdings 3"
End If

End Sub
```

When I got everything in place, I tried making a more "proper" – less repetitions – piece of code:

```
Sub changeGroup2(selVal As String)

For i = 1 To 3
    With grp.GroupItems(i)
        If selVal = "Kollektiv" Then
            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
                Select Case i
                    Case 1
                        .Text = "S"
                    Case 2
                        .Text = "-"
                    Case 3
                        .Text = "h"
                End Select
                If i = 2 Then .Font.Size = 9 Else .Font.Size = 11
                If i = 3 Then .Font.Name = "Wingdings 3" Else .Font.Name = "+mn-lt"
            End With
        Else
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
            Select Case i
                Case 1
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                Case 2
                    If selVal = "Fordon" Then .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Else .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                Case 3
                    .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
            End Select
        End If
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

But due to the many variations in the shapes, I ended up with something just as long, but harder to follow.

Then I tried combining the `case select` statements, but then I was forced to repeat the `If` instead:

```
Sub changeGroup3(selVal As String)

For i = 1 To 3
    With grp.GroupItems(i)
                Select Case i
                    Case 1
                        If selVal = "Kollektiv" Then
                            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "S"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                        Else
                            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        End If
                    Case 2
                        If selVal = "Kollektiv" Then .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "-" Else: .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
                        If selVal = "Fordon" Then .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0) Else .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                    Case 3
                        If selVal = "Kollektiv" Then
                            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "h"
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
                        Else
                            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = ""
                            .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 176, 80)
                        End if
                End Select
                If i = 2 Then .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 9 Else .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = 11
                If i = 3 Then .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = "Wingdings 3" Else .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
Next i

End Sub
```

So the question is, which is the proper way to go?
Repeating code for readability, or trying as hard as possible to minimize repetition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you first wrote is easy to follow but is quite detailed, therefore it is not easy to see what's going on.

To improve this, you could define some helper subs to reduce the amound of typing. For example:

```vb
Sub SetColorAndText(byval index as Integer, byval color as ???, byval text as String)
End Sub
```

This simple sub already captures most of the repetition that is going on.

Alternatively, can you achieve the same result using the standard conditional formatting feature? That might be simpler overall.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I use a couple of helper subs when drawing the shapes and creating the groups in the first place. So it might be a lot easier to actually just redraw the whole thing using existing subs, rather than modifying the current objects. I should look into that. Not sure  I got the conditional formatting suggestion however. Can that be used on shapes?

Answer (score 2):

Use constants to name your `RGB()` values.

```
Const Green As Long = RGB(0, 176, 80)
```

Use `VBA.ColorConstants` when available:

- RGB(255, 0, 0): VBA.ColorConstants.vbRed
- RGB(255, 255, 255): VBA.ColorConstants.vbWhite

---

Adding blank lines between groups will make you code more readable easier to modify.

The `Font.Name` and `Font.Size` are only modified if the the `selVal` = "Kollektiv". Once `changeGroup("Kollektiv")` is called these settings are locked in.

Without reading the code it is not obvious what `selVal` does.  I would give it a more relevant name (such as: Format, SelectionType, SelectedFormat, FormatIndex).

### Version 1

```
Sub changeGroup(Format As String)
    Const Green As Long = RGB(0, 176, 80)
    Dim Index As Long
    Index = Switch(Format= "Fordon", 0, Format = "Fotg", 1, Format = "Kollektiv", 2)

    Rem grp.GroupItems(1): Add  Description
    grp.GroupItems(1).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(vbRed, vbRed, vbWhite)(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Array("", "", "S")(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 11)(Index)

    Rem grp.GroupItems(2): Add  Description
    grp.GroupItems(2).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(Green, vbWhite, vbWhite)(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Array("", "", "-")(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(2).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 9)(Index)

    Rem grp.GroupItems(3): Add  Description
    grp.GroupItems(3).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(Green, Green, vbWhite)(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = Array("", "", "h")(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 11)(Index)
    grp.GroupItems(3).TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Font.Name = Array("Calibri", "Calibri", "Wingdings 3")(Index)


End Sub
```

### Version 2

```
Sub changeGroup(Format As String)
    Const Green As Long = Green
    Dim Index As Long
    Index = Switch(Format = "Fordon", 0, Format = "Fotg", 1, Format = "Kollektiv", 2)

    Rem grp.GroupItems(1): Add  Description
    With grp.GroupItems(1)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(vbRed, vbRed, vbWhite)(Index)
        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
            .Text = Array("", "", "S")(Index)
            .Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 11)(Index)
        End With
    End With

    Rem grp.GroupItems(2): Add  Description
    With grp.GroupItems(2)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(Green, vbWhite, vbWhite)(Index)
        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
            .Text = Array("", "", "-")(Index)
            .Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 11)(Index)
        End With
    End With

    Rem grp.GroupItems(3): Add  Description
    With grp.GroupItems(3)
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = Array(Green, Green, vbWhite)(Index)
        With .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters
            .Text = Array("", "", "h")(Index)
            .Font.Size = Array(9, 9, 11)(Index)
            .Font.Name = Array("Calibri", "Calibri", "Wingdings 3")(Index)
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Good suggestions. I actually did use constants from my RGB value in the code that creates the shapes in the first place, not sure why I didn't stick with that. I really like that `Index = Switch` solution. That should come in handy. I decided to scrap the whole thing in the end, just delete the group and use the old that creates it in the first place to just make a new one. But I might be able to implement some of this in that code instead. I wrote that 3 years ago, so could probably use a rework.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber if it ain't broke don't fix it....lol